# Can jenkins Pipeline force storing everything in VCS?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have used Jenkins DSL. Now I started a new project and considering using Pipeline instead Jenkins DSL.

When using Jenkins DSL there was a seed job and everybody was forced to store every job in version control in order to not have it overwritten.
I cannot find a way for forcing the same thing with Pipeline.

I liked this approach, because in my opinion it really helps to store everything in VCS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Pipeline, you need to create the job configuration manually like the Job DSL seed job.

You can use a mixed approach by using Job DSL for creating the Pipeline jobs and keep the pipeline definition in a `Jenkinsfile` next to your project's code.

```
pipelineJob('example') {
  definition {
    cpsScm {
      scm {
        git('https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin.git')
      }
      scriptPath('Jenkinsfile')
    }
  }
}
```

See https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/pipelineJob for details.

Also checkout the advanced Pipeline job types like Multibranch and Organization Folder which provide a dynamic job setup out-of-the-box. See https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/. The job types are also supported by Job DSL.